# Repair ripped carpet

Tags: repair, carpet, stain, damage

We bought a contemporary newly designed carpet. But it has only been a week now, and the carpet has started to show some damage even though we haven't used it. There was a particular blackish yellow stain in a corner and some parts of the carpet are ripped.

There was no problem whatsoever when buying the carpet as it wasn't the problem of the purchase. Could someone help me out with a suggestion to repair this ripped carpet situation?

Comment: Did you install the carpet yourself, or have it professionally installed? I mean, carpet does not rip itself, somebody or thing caused this and if it was the installer then they should own up and fix it. If it was you then please simplify the question and just ask "how to fix ripped carpet" and attach a photo to help people help you.

Comment: I ordered it online and they installed it. The carpet was fine when it was delivered. There was no damage. But this happened recently as we never actually used it properly. I tried attaching a photo but it wasn't visible properly.

Comment: put your photo on Imgur and post a link in another comment, a user will embed it for you.

Comment: It was fine when "delivered"... but no post-install acceptance inspection by you...?

Comment: Of course, I inspected it, that's why I said it was "fine". I meant there was no damage when it was delivered.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You haven't used the carpet, but it's ripped and stained? What??

Comment: I wonder if "Robert Earl" is a shell profile for the spammer below.

Comment: With the limited information and possible questionable post I vote to close. If a picture shows up we will try and answer the question as the carpet may have been over stretched but the installer should be contacted , and if they do not get back to you contact the BBB, and contractors license board.